# textarea is removing new line only if it comes first

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hard to explain, but for some reason when I grab content (in php) that contains new lines at the start of a file (Like this):

```
Hello world!
```

and `echo($content);` it into a `<textarea>`; It is shown like this:

```
Hello world!
```

It ONLY removes the first line (if there is one that's blank).

---

But if I do this in JavaScript: `textarea.innerHTML = '<?PHP echo($content); ?>'` it works (not ideal tho, I am trying to stear away from this)..

Really could use the help because I am dumbfounded right now :S

EDIT: Also, it only happens if the new lines come before any text/strings.
For example this will be retrieved like this and displayed like this:

```
Hello world, this will work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a newline immediately after the `<textarea>` tag is not included in its value. This allows you to write something like:

```
<textarea name="somename">
this is some
contents
</textarea>
```

without the value containing a newline before `this`; it's treated equivalent to

```
<textarea name="somename">this is some
contents
</textarea>
```

So the solution is to always put a newline after `<textarea>` before the variable.

```
<textarea>
<?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
```