# newline character not converting to line break in php text area post

Tags: php

when i assign a text with newline character and use nl2br function it converts newline to line break but same doesn't happen with textarea post. I want to know why this is happening and also how to convert the newline character from textarea post of a form, to line-break when it is echoed . Below is my code :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
        $var = "One line.\nAnother line.";
        echo nl2br($var);
        echo nl2br($_POST['comment']);
        // One line.\nAnother line.
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
  <label for="lname">Commment</label><br>
  <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40">One line.\nAnother line.</textarea><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To get a new line in a textarea you need to hit the *Enter* key in your keyboard, not literally type `\n`. A textarea isn't a code editor or a programming language.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65893245/textarea-is-removing-new-line-only-if-it-comes-first

Comment: Basically I want to take a string like this input in text are "One line.\nAnother line." .And send it in mail. But in mail it should show in two different lines.

Comment: @"Álvaro González" you mean to say there is no way to take string like this "One line.\nAnother line." as input and print it as two separate line.

Comment: I'm not saying that. What I mean is that backslash entities like `\n` do not exist in HTML. If you type `\n` in a website's textarea you don't get a line feed because that isn't how HTML works. But your PHP code can take any string and convert it to whatever you see fit. You can even convert `:rabbit:` to `` if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an actual linebreak in you `<textarea>`. `\n` wont work there.

`nl2br` converts linebreaks to html `<br>`.

With php-code you can add a linebreak like this:

```
<textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40">One line.<?= "\n" ?>Another line.</textarea>
```

Or you spimply write:

```
<textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40">One line.
Another line.</textarea>
```

If you want to reuse the submitted value:

```
<textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?= htmlentities($_POST['comment']) ?></textarea>
```

Be careful here, you want to sanitize your user-input with `htmlentities($_POST['comment'])` or the user will be able to alter the page.

### Additional info

`<?= $var ?>` is the short form of `<?php echo $var; ?>`

### References

- [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities)

Comment: Basically I want to take a string like this input in text are "One line.\nAnother line." .And send it in mail. But in mail it should show in two different lines.

Comment: Then use `str_replace('\n', "\n", $text)` for an text mail. `str_replace('\n', '<br>', $text)` for a html-mail. Notice the singelquotes, they are used to NOT convert `\n` to a linebreak, so you can search and replace your `\n`.